# Solving a recurrence relation using the substitution method

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the recursive function $f(n)=3f(n/4)+2n $, $f(16)=32.$

Where n is always a power of 4 greater than 16.

We must find a closed form utilizing substitutions.

So, after one substitution, f(n) could be written as:

$$ f(n)= 3^{2} \cdot f(\frac{n}{4^{2}})+\frac{3\cdot2n}{4}+2n $$
And after two substitutions, it would look like:

$$ f(n)= 3^{3} \cdot f(\frac{n}{4^{3}})+ \frac{3^{2}\cdot2n}{4^{2}}+\frac{3\cdot2n}{4}+2n $$

In a standardized form:

$$ f(n)= 3^{k} \cdot f(\frac{n}{4^{k}})+ \frac{3^{k-1}\cdot2n}{4^{k-1}}+ ... +\frac{3\cdot2n}{4}+2n $$

Consider that this series: $\frac{3^{k-1}\cdot2n}{4^{k-1}}+ ... +\frac{3\cdot2n}{4}+2n $ Is a geometric series that should evaluate to $8n$ right?

And also, since we need $f(\frac{n}{4^{k}})=f(16)$, then $k=\frac{\log(n)}{log(4)}-2$

Then f(n) should be:

$$f(n)=3^{\log{n}/log{4} -2}\cdot32 + 8n$$

Yet this is obviously wrong by simply plugging in values. I believe my mistake is that the geometric series does not converge to $8n$, since I am completely disregarding the variable $k$ and that seems wrong.

Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: My first step would be to write $n = 4^m$, and rewrite the entire recurrence relation in terms of $m$, setting $g(m) = f(n)$, in order to make things more legible. It's hard to follow why your first statement about $f(n)$ should be true. If it is, it still doesn't make sense to evaluate the series as an infinite sum, rather than taking a partial sum.

Comment: @user208259 I added some clarification on how I made the first statement!

Comment: You need the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series, not the sum of the infinite series. It's $b + ba + ba^2 + \dots ba^k = \sum_{i=0}^k ba^i = b(a^{k+1} - 1)/(a-1)$